# How to initialize dynamic creates classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I create dynamically classesfor my MongoDB models during run time:

```
  k = Class.new()do
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic
    ...
    ...
  end
```

I have an objecgt *entity* which has an attribute *lookup*. When I create my new class k I want to assign entity.lookup to this new class so I can lateron access this attribute lookup:

```
puts k.lookup
```

How can I do this? I tried many things (for example):

```
  k = Class.new()do
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

    attr_accessor :lookup

    @lookup = entity.lookup
    ...
    ...
  end
```

But this doesnt work! Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Important thing to understand is that `k` is a class. It doesn't have the (dynamic) property 'lookup`. Only instances of that class can have that. Observe:

```
k = Class.new do
  include Mongoid::Document

  store_in collection: 'kk'

  field :lookup, type: String, default: 'blah'
end


k.new.lookup # => 'blah'
```

Comment: I further on get an instance of my klass k:

d = k.where(...)

So how can I get my 'lookup' which I know during the class creation later on when I have an instance of this class?

Comment: @MichaelH. Try this `d.lookup`

Comment: @MichaelH.: then `d` is not an instance of that class (but something else). Try my working code. And compare with what you do

Comment: My issue is I know entity.lookup during the class k creation and want to set it during class creation. Lateron when I create an instance of my class K entity.lookup is no longer available.

Comment: @MichaelH. Impossible. You can see in the code above that it works.

Comment: But I can set default values for fields during class creation which is possible. I need to do something similar - I am setting a defaulft value but attr_accessor doesnt know defaults.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163191/discussion-between-michael-h-and-sergio-tulentsev).